# OpenAI Gym problem override ObservationWrapper reset() method

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, openai-gym, pong, dqn

I've been trying to solve the pong atari with a DQN. I'm using OpenAI gym for the pong environment.

I've made a custom ObservationWrapper but I'm unable to figure out whats the problem with the reset() method I've overriden.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\berna\Documents\Pytorch Experiment\Torching the Dead Grass\DeepQLearning\training.py", line 123, in <module>
    agent = Agent(env, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\berna\Documents\Pytorch Experiment\Torching the Dead Grass\DeepQLearning\training.py", line 56, in __init__
    self._reset()
  File "C:\Users\berna\Documents\Pytorch Experiment\Torching the Dead Grass\DeepQLearning\training.py", line 59, in _reset
    self.state = env.reset()
  File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gym\core.py", line 379, in reset
    obs, info = self.env.reset(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\berna\Documents\Pytorch Experiment\Torching the Dead Grass\DeepQLearning\wrappers.py", line 106, in reset
    return self.observation(self.env.reset())
  File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gym\core.py", line 379, in reset
    obs, info = self.env.reset(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\berna\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\gym\core.py", line 379, in reset
    obs, info = self.env.reset(**kwargs)
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

and the code:

Agent:

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, env, exp_buffer):
        self.env = env
        self.exp_buffer = exp_buffer
        self._reset()

    def _reset(self):
        self.state = env.reset()
        self.total_reward = 0.0
```

wrapper:

```
class BufferWrapper(gym.ObservationWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env, n_steps, dtype=np.float32):
        super(BufferWrapper, self).__init__(env)
        self.dtype = dtype
        old_space = env.observation_space
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(old_space.low.repeat(n_steps, axis=0),
                                                old_space.high.repeat(n_steps, axis=0), dtype=dtype)

    def reset(self):
        self.buffer = np.zeros_like(self.observation_space.low, dtype=self.dtype)
        return self.observation(self.env.reset())

    def observation(self, observation):
        self.buffer[:-1] = self.buffer[1:]
        self.buffer[-1] = observation
        return self.buffer
```

Can someone helping me understand why I'm receiving that error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make 2 changes in your code.

1. In the **reset** method you have to **return**, not just the **obervation** as you did, but also the **return_info** parameter.
   https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/env/#gymnasium.Env.reset
2. Also in the **reset** method you should accept **seed** and **options**. By including  ****kwargs** as an argument you will be covered.

your code should be:

```
class BufferWrapper(gym.ObservationWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env, n_steps, dtype=np.float32):
        super(BufferWrapper, self).__init__(env)
        self.dtype = dtype
        old_space = env.observation_space
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(old_space.low.repeat(n_steps, axis=0),
                                                old_space.high.repeat(n_steps, axis=0), dtype=dtype)

    def reset(self, **kwargs):
        self.buffer = np.zeros_like(self.observation_space.low, dtype=self.dtype)
        obs, info = self.env.reset(**kwargs)
        return self.observation(obs), info

    def observation(self, observation):
        self.buffer[:-1] = self.buffer[1:]
        self.buffer[-1] = observation
        return self.buffer
```

Also i want you to notice that if you have a wrapper acting on the **step** method, you also have to update it to  **return** parameters **terminated** and **truncated**.